# Remotely run interactive plink session on another computer

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, plink

Currently users RDP from their workstation to a server over a VPN and then run putty from that server to connect to the customer's server over a different VPN. We are unable to create a separate physical or logical path to the customer's server because there are some finicky configurations on their end so that the legacy software will still function.

How can I configure a way to allow our users to pivot off of our server to the customer's server directly from their workstations without using RDP to connect via SSH to the customer with an interactive prompt?
I've been trying to use plink, but I'm open to suggestions of other software if needed.

Below is a basic picture showing the connectivity.
[image: Network diagram]

Comment: To be clear: You want to be able to establish an interactive session from a remote office workstation, over a VPN, through a Windows server, over another VPN, to an SSH server? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The origination IP must be that of the Windows server, otherwise the legacy software won't work.